# Which lifecycle is best for using Entity Framework with Autofac in ASP.Net MVC?

Tags: c#, autofac, autofac-configuration

I am new to Autofac and I am using it as a dependency container. I want to register my DB context. This is what I've done

```
public static class AutofacConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterComponents()
        {
            var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

            builder.RegisterType<MyEntities>().As<IMyEntities>().SingleInstance().PreserveExistingDefaults();
            var container = builder.Build();

            GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.UseAutofacActivator(container);
            
            DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new AutofacDependencyResolver(container));
        }
    }
```

But In .net Core, I need to register my DBContext as `Scoped`. Is it correct to register my Entities here as `SingleInstance` or I should change it?

Comment: If MyEntities type depends on your implementation of the DbContext you have to register it as Scoped.

Answer (score 0):

According to MS docs [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/dbcontext-configuration/) "A DbContext instance is designed to be used for a single unit-of-work." From experience I've found registering a DBContext as a `SingleInstance` often leads to difficult to reproduce exceptions, especially in a multi threaded environment.

I would consider giving it as smaller scope as possible to achieve a unit of work, such as `InstancePerLifetimeScope`